# How to use existing integer sort to sort integer tuples?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Does anyone know of an efficient algorithm to use an existing integer sort (such as the STL sort) to sort integer tuples without modifying the existing integer sort.  E.g. I want to sort a list of 4 integer tuples.  Tuples are in the form: `<int,int,int, int>`.  Again assume the integer sort can only deal with single ints.

Comment: Do you want to sort a container where each element is a tuple, or do you want to sort an individual tuple??

Comment: And assuming you want to sort the list, which comes first, <2,2,2,2> or <3,1,1,1>?

Answer (score 6):

You can sort anything you want using existing C++ sorting routine "sort", by just defining your own comparison function, For eg in your case

```
sort(mytuplearray, mytuplearray + N, mycomp)
```

where mycomp is

```
bool mycomp(tuple& a, tuple& b)
{
     //compare however you like
}
```

Comment: You can even use the default for tuples, a lexicographical comparison, which is most likely what one would want in this case.

Comment: I think you want `const tuple&` for the `mycomp` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a lexicographic tuple comparator using a scalar comparator, simply compare the last pair of components that is not equal. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class LexicographicCompare
{
private:

    T Compare;

public:

    LexicographicCompare(T Compare) : Compare(Compare)
    {
    }

    bool operator()
        ( const tuple<int, int, int> & a
        , const tuple<int, int, int> & b
        ) const
    {
        if (a[0] != b[0])
            return Compare(a[0], b[0]);
        if (a[1] != b[1])
            return Compare(a[1], b[1]);
        return Compare(a[2], b[2]);
    }
};

sort(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), LexicographicCompare(IntCompare()));
```

Comment: `operator<` is overloaded for tuples to do just this exact thing.

Comment: I have not used boost::Tuple, so not sure they can take comparison functions for their elements. After all, Arya wanted to reuse arbitrary integer comparisons (as far as I can tell).